# Using a select in an update statement via ADO

Tags: sql, vbscript, adodb

I can run this query in my database tool no problems:

```sql
UPDATE table1 
SET    NAME = 'John' 
WHERE  userid IN (SELECT Max(userid) 
                  FROM   table1 
                  WHERE  userid = NULL)
```

That runs successfully.  When I try to run this exact same statement from a VBScript I don't get any errors and the update doesn't occur. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```vb
Public Function GetAvailableRow()
  Dim conn, command

  On Error Resume Next

  Set conn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
  Set command = CreateObject("adodb.command")

  conn.IsolationLevel = 1048576

  conn.Open "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise}; Server=myserver;port=myport; db=mydatabase;uid=userid;pwd=password;"

  command.ActiveConnection = conn
  command.CommandText = "UPDATE table1 SET name = 'John' WHERE userid in (SELECT MAX(userid) from table1 where userid = NULL)"

  conn.BeginTrans 
  command.Execute
  conn.CommitTrans

  conn.Close

  Set command = Nothing
  Set conn = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

`userid = NULL` in the `where` clause will always return unknown. Hence, the update won't occur.

use `userid is null` instead.

Comment: Just wondering how OP say running the query on db works ok on first place.

Comment: Great catch!  I didn't even think about that.   That fixed it.  Thank you!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I promise you that works.  I ran it three times in DBArtisan and it worked every time.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza..the query will run but the where clause doesn't return any rows to update.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I don't understand why it works but I assure you on my honor that it finds an available row and runs the update.  No joke.